# How do I handle an API response with useState to update a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, promise

I am working on an API response. My aim is to take this API response to update a specified state.

Here the neccessary code snippet from my functional componenet:

```
const [recordImagesPayload, setRecordImagesPayload] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
    // const payload = JSON.stringify({ ...createPayload(), recordImage: newImage });

    request(`${url}`, { headers, method: 'GET' })
      .then((response: any) => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        var obj = JSON.parse(json);
        var res: any = [];
        for (var i in obj) {
          res.push(obj[i]);
        }
        setRecordImagesPayload(res);
        console.log(res);
      });
  }, []);
```

My console.is not showing the res from my last line of code. I am probably doing something wrong with the response but I don't know what to do.

Please help.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the request function is using fetch function, in that case you are already parsing the json response using response.json() call, so the resolved value in the next then is not json, so you don't have to use JSON.parse there

Try running this. Here instead of creating a new array and for loop, we can just use Object.values

```
useEffect(() => {
        const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
        // const payload = JSON.stringify({ ...createPayload(), recordImage: newImage });
    
        request(`${url}`, { headers, method: 'GET' })
          .then((response: any) => response.json())
          .then(result => {
            const res = Object.values(result);
            setRecordImagesPayload(res);
            console.log(res);
          });
      }, []);
```

Comment: Hi Akhil. Many thanks. However, when I am console logging my recordImagesPayload, it shows an empty array. Do you know why?

Comment: @BenFisher state update is asynchronous, so I think if we try to log the result immediately after a state update we won't see the updated state. If the result object has values then it will definitely update the state.

you please use the  recordImagePayload inside the JSX.
Or if you need to do something immediately after this state updates, you can use a separate useEffect and give this state as dependancy and inside it you can write the code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Akhil. I had a minor issue in my code regarding Typescript which was leading to the issue. The type of the result wasn't specified, but beside that, Akhil's answer was very accurate. Many thanks for the quick response and support.

Here is the final code which worked for me:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
        // const payload = JSON.stringify({ ...createPayload(), recordImage: newImage });
    
        request(`${url}`, { headers, method: 'GET' })
          .then((response: any) => response.json())
          .then(result: any => {
            const res = Object.values(result);
            setRecordImagesPayload(res);
            console.log(res);
          });
      }, []);
```